# How to compare int arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays

When I am trying to compare two int array, even though they are exactly the same, the code inside `if (one == two)` still doesn't get executed. Why is this?

```
Object[] one = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
Object[] two = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

if (one == two){
    System.out.println("equal");
} else {
    System.out.println("not equal");
}
```

Comment: you can use `Arrays.equals(one,two)`. Please remember that, here order matters.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. may i ask why I can't compare two int array using ==?

Comment: When you compare two int arrays using == , you are actually comparing array references not the content of the array.

Comment: @TonyStark because if you do one == two you are comparing the references and not the content...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A few things to note here:

- `==` compares the references, not the values . . . that is, you are asking whether these two arrays are the same exact instance, not whether they contain the same values.
- The fact that you are using `==` means you may not know about the [`equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) method on [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). This is **not** the method you'll need to solve this current problem, but just be aware that in general, when you compare the values of two objects, you should be using `obj1.equals(obj2)`, not `obj1 == obj2`. Now `==` **does** work with primitives like `int` (e.g. plain old `x == 3` and so on), so maybe that's why you were using it, but I just wanted to make sure you were aware of `equals()` vs. `==`.
- In the old old days (pre-1998), you would have to compare each element pair of the two arrays.  Nowadays, you can just use that static [`Arrays.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals-int:A-int:A-) method on the [`java.util.Arrays`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class.  This method is overloaded for all the primitive types (using `==` under the hood for each element pair) and for `Object` (where it will most definitely use `equals()` for each pair.)

Comment: This is a decent answer but the question is poorly researched and has been asked before. For everyone's sake: look for a duplicate before answering -- it will save both you and the asker time and avoids duplicating efforts.

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator does a reference equality check on objects (which arrays are). If the array elements are primitive (like `int`), you can use [`java.util.Arrays.equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals(int[],%20int[])). If they are themselves Objects, [`java.util.Arrays.deepEquals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object[])) will do a deep equality test (provided the Objects in the array supply a suitable override of `Object#equals`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that:

```
public boolean compareArrays(int[] a, int[] b) {
    boolean check = true;
    if (a!= null && b!= null){
      if (a.length != b.length){
          check= false;
      }else
          for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
              if (b[i] != a[i]) {
                  check= false;    
              }                 
        }
    }else{
      check= false;
    }
    return check;
}
```

Or you could do something like that:

```
boolean areEqual = Arrays.equals(Arrays.sort(arr1), Arrays.sort(arr2));
```

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing references. Compare the content instead with: `Arrays.equals(one, two)`

Answer (score 1):

If you do this:

```
if (one == two){
```

then yo are comparing the references of the 2 arrays and not their content and that is wrong..

do instead

```
Arrays.equals(one, two)
```

Answer (score 1):

`==` operator compares **references** and not actual values of everything that extends Object in java. This approach works on primitives only.